# Olympiad Algebra Polynomial Regarding Exponential Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> There exists a degree 4 polynomial M(y) such that M(y)=2<sup>y</sup> for y = 1,2,3,4,5. Find M(6).

This problem appeared on my IOQM (Indian Olympiad Qualifiers for Mathematics) mock test paper. The official solution is very incomprehensive and it uses the combinatorial formula of 2<sup>y</sup> (i.e. - 

∑
<sup>n</sup>C<sub>k</sub>


) Which I also don't understand. Does anyone have a different solution?

Comment: The simplest approach is to use the method of differences - see for example here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/

Comment: Thanks Chris, appreciate ur efforts :)

Comment: I've just posted the method as an answer. Maybe this isn't so well known? But you can see it makes this problem trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the method of differences approach I mentioned in the comments. For me, this is far easier than explicitly calculating coefficients.

Each column contains the difference between entries in the previous column. (Since the entries are mostly powers of $2$, this happens to mean a lot of repeats; but you can try it for a different polynomial). Since $M$ is a quartic, repeating this process $4$ times yields a constant value. For convenience, say $M(6)=V$.

| $y$ | $M(y)$ | diff | diff | diff | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $2$ | $2$ | $2$ | $2$ | $2$ |
| $2$ | $4$ | $4$ | $4$ | $4$ | $V-60$ |
| $3$ | $8$ | $8$ | $8$ | $V-56$ | . |
| $4$ | $16$ | $16$ | $V-48$ | . | . |
| $5$ | $32$ | $V-32$ | . | . | . |
| $6$ | $V$ | . | . | . | . |

Hence $V-60=2$; ie $M(6)=62$. Note the only operation we had to do here was subtraction.

Comment: Woww amazing approach sir, didn't know about this method till today

Answer (score 3):

There is a very down to earth approach to this that uses no special knowledge. Write $M(y) = ay^4+by^3+cy^2+dy+e$. From the formula $M(y) = 2^y$ when $y=1,2,3,4,5$ we get
\begin{align}
a+b+c+d+e&=2\\
2^4a+2^3b+2^2c+2d+e &= 2^2\\
3^4a+3^3b+3^2c+3d+e &= 2^3\\
4^4a+4^3b+4^2c+4d+e &= 2^4\\
5^4a+5^3b+5^2c+5d+e &= 2^5\\
\end{align}

This is a linear system which you can easily solve to find the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$, which determines $M$ completely, so you can calculate $M(6)$.

This might be a little tedious, so you can use [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) instead. The explicit formula is
$$M(y) = \sum_{j=1}^52^j\prod_{1\leq i \leq 5\\ \ \ \ i\neq j}\frac{y-i}{j-i} = \frac 1{12}(y^4-6y^3+23y^2-18y+24).$$
Thus, $M(6) = 62$. You can even calculate it without expanding the polynomial:
\begin{align}M(6) &= \sum_{j=1}^52^j\prod_{1\leq i \leq 5\\ \ \ \ i\neq j}\frac{6-i}{j-i}\\ &=  2^1 \frac {(6 - 5) (6 - 4) (6 - 3) (6 - 2)} {(1 - 
       5) (1 - 4) (1 - 3) (1 - 2) }+ 
 2^2 \frac {(6 - 5) (6 - 4) (6 - 3)  (6 - 1)} {(2 - 
       5) (2 - 4) (2 - 3)  (2 - 1)}+ 
 2^3 \frac {(6 - 5) (6 - 4)  (6 - 2) (6 - 1)} {(3 - 
       5) (3 - 4)  (3 - 2) (3 - 1)}+ 
 2^4 \frac {(6 - 5)  (6 - 3) (6 - 2) (6 - 1)} {(4 - 
       5)  (4 - 3) (4 - 2) (4 - 1)}+ 
 2^5 \frac { (6 - 4) (6 - 3) (6 - 2) (6 - 1)} { (5 - 4) (5 - 3) (5 - 2) (5 - 1)}\end{align}

---

The formula for the Lagrange polynomial might look a bit scary, but the point is that $\prod_{1\leq i \leq 5\\ \ \ \ i\neq j}\frac{y-i}{j-i}$ evaluates to $1$ when $y = j$ and to $0$ when $y\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus\{j\}$, so the summands in $\sum_{j=1}^52^j\prod_{1\leq i \leq 5\\ \ \ \ i\neq j}\frac{y-i}{j-i}$ are all $0$ for $y = j$, except one that is equal to $2^j$, which is precisely the value that we wanted for $M(j)$.

Comment: Ohhh yeah, Lagrange interpolation is something I learnt for a while last year but never revised, Lagrange formula seems like a smart way to approach this yeah

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to solve for $a,b,c,d,e:$

$$\begin{align} p(x)=a&+b(x-1)\\&+c(x-1)(x-2)\\&+d(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\\&+e(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4). \end{align}$$

Then $$\begin{align}2&=p(1)=a\\4&=p(2)=a+b\\
8&=p(3)=a+2b+2c\\
16&=p(4)=a+3b+6c+6d\\
32&=p(5)=a+4b+12c+24d+24e
\end{align}$$

These are much easier to solve, and then: $$p(6)=a+5b+20c+60d+120e$$

Comment: Oh thanks, that was seemingly easy lol, just a lil tedious. Thanks for the efforts sir

Answer (score 1):

There is this famous problem where you [divide a circle into regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas) and the greatest possible number of regions grows like *1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...*

It turns out that the solution for the number of regions (see the Wikipedia page for many possible derivations of the result) is a degree 4 polynomial $p(y)$ (such that $p(y) = 2^y$, for $y\in\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4,\}$) and you are looking for $M(y) = 2 p(y - 1)$.

Comment: Ooh that's smth new, will definitely check up on those links

Answer (score 0):

Let us do the job explicitly, we start with a "structural" mode to solve a *related* linear system, where the (extended) matrix of the system is of Vandermonde shape. We obtain explicit formulas for the unknowns, explaining
why the key-word Lagrange appears in the context, and the explicit values for the unknowns resemble some binomial coefficients...

---

Let $$M(Y)= a+bY+cY^2+dY^3+eY^4$$
be the polynomial of degree four claimed to exist. The conditions $M(k)=2^k$ for $k$ among $1,2,3,4,5$ can be written in matrix form. We prepend multiplicatively to this writing the next magenta row matrix with unknowns $s,t,u,v,w$:
$$
M(6)=
\underbrace{
\color{magenta}{
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v& w
\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1^1 & 1^2 & 1^3 & 1^4 \\
1 & 2^1 & 2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 \\
1 & 3^1 & 3^2 & 3^3 & 3^4 \\
1 & 4^1 & 4^2 & 4^3 & 4^4 \\
1 & 5^1 & 5^2 & 5^3 & 5^4 
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{arrange to be }\color{blue}{[1 \ 6\ 6^2\ 6^3\ 6^4]}}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d\\e
\end{bmatrix}
=
\color{magenta}{
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v& w
\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2^1\\2^2\\2^3\\2^4\\2^5
\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
We make a choice of $s,t,u,v,w$ such that the product of the first two matrices is the vector with components $1,6,6^2,6^3,6^4$, needed in the computation of $M(6)$.
We obtain a system in $s,t,u,v,w$, and Cramer's rule gives for instance explicitly for $s$, by replacing the "s-row" in the matrix of the system by the blue coefficients row:
$$
s =
\frac
{\qquad
\begin{vmatrix}
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{6^1} & \color{blue}{6^2} & \color{blue}{6^3} & \color{blue}{6^4} \\
1 & 2^1 & 2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 \\
1 & 3^1 & 3^2 & 3^3 & 3^4 \\
1 & 4^1 & 4^2 & 4^3 & 4^4 \\
1 & 5^1 & 5^2 & 5^3 & 5^4 
\end{vmatrix}
\qquad}
{\qquad
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1^1 & 1^2 & 1^3 & 1^4 \\
1 & 2^1 & 2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 \\
1 & 3^1 & 3^2 & 3^3 & 3^4 \\
1 & 4^1 & 4^2 & 4^3 & 4^4 \\
1 & 5^1 & 5^2 & 5^3 & 5^4 
\end{vmatrix}
\qquad}
=
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-2)(\color{blue}6-3)(\color{blue}6-4)(\color{blue}6-5)}
{(\color{green}1-2)(\color{green}1-3)(\color{green}1-4)(\color{green}1-5)}\ .
$$
We have used the formula for the determinant of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), and a lot of factors cancel each other in the denominator and the numerator, both determinants of Vendermonde matrices. We can do so also for the other coefficients, thus obtaining:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\color{magenta}s &= 
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-2)(\color{blue}6-3)(\color{blue}6-4)(\color{blue}6-5)}
{(\color{green}1-2)(\color{green}1-3)(\color{green}1-4)(\color{green}1-5)}
=
+\frac{4.3.2.1}{1.2.3.4}=+1\ ,
\\
\color{magenta}t &= 
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-1)(\color{blue}6-3)(\color{blue}6-4)(\color{blue}6-5)}
{(\color{green}2-1)(\color{green}2-3)(\color{green}2-4)(\color{green}2-5)}
=
-\frac{5.3.2.1}{1.1.2.3}=-5\ ,
\\
\color{magenta}u &= 
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-1)(\color{blue}6-2)(\color{blue}6-4)(\color{blue}6-5)}
{(\color{green}3-1)(\color{green}3-2)(\color{green}3-4)(\color{green}3-5)}
=
+\frac{5.4.2.1}{2.1.1.2}=+10\ ,
\\
\color{magenta}v &= 
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-1)(\color{blue}6-2)(\color{blue}6-3)(\color{blue}6-5)}
{(\color{green}4-1)(\color{green}4-2)(\color{green}4-3)(\color{green}4-5)}
=
-\frac{5.4.3.1}{3.2.1.1}=-10\ ,
\\
\color{magenta}w &= 
\frac
{(\color{blue}6-1)(\color{blue}6-2)(\color{blue}6-3)(\color{blue}6-4)}
{(\color{green}5-1)(\color{green}5-2)(\color{green}5-3)(\color{green}5-4)}
=
+\frac{5.4.3.2}{4.3.2.1}=+5\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We can use these values now to compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
M(6)
&=
\color{magenta}{
\begin{bmatrix}
1& -5& 10& -10& 5
\end{bmatrix}
}
\begin{bmatrix}
2^1\\2^2\\2^3\\2^4\\2^5
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=2\Big(\ 1-5\cdot 2^1+10\cdot 2^2-10\cdot 2^3+5\cdot 2^4 -2^5\ \Big)+2\cdot 2^5
\\
&=2\cdot\Big(\ (1-2)^5+2^5\ \Big)=2(-1+32)=\bbox[yellow]{\ 62\ }\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Amazing approach sir, thanks for the efforts :)